# numpy / signal correlation returning "inf"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, correlation

So I am trying to align signals (in this case both signals are speed in km/h) and I am trying to use np.correlate or signal.correlate to do this.

However, both of those come back with [inf]. They run, no errors. Its just inf. If I switch the mode for correlate to "Full" it takes about 10 seconds and returns a 1-D array that does have numbers in it, but most entries are actually inf too!

This is the code for taking the two signals from two separate datasets and working out how much to pad by. The datasets are Frames with time column set as the index. So I convert the two from DataFrame to ndarray. I did this because when I do the padding, the padded result also comes back as an array rather than a frame.

```
a = pems_log["GPS_VehicleSpeed"] #pluck speed channel from main dataset. stays as frame
a = np.atleast_1d(np.asarray(a)) # convert to just numbers or ndarray?
b = can_log["speed_obd"]
b = np.atleast_1d(np.asarray(b))

if(len(a)!=len(b)):
    pad_length = abs(len(a)-len(b))
    if(len(a)<len(b)):
        a_padded = biDirPad(a,pad_length)
        b_padded = b 
    else:
        b_padded = biDirPad(b,pad_length)
        #test = biDirPad(can_log,pad_length) # you can just pad an entire dataFrame. Function modified to just pad top and bottom on 2D.
        a_padded = a 

print(len(a))
print(len(b))
print(pad_length)
print(len(a_padded), len(b_padded))
```

this is the function for padding. I wanted to use the method where you pad either end of the data set to make the shorter one the same length. I used "edge" mode to just copy the end rows out to the new end points.

```
def biDirPad(sig,padVal):
    dimensions=sig.ndim
    if dimensions==2:
        return np.pad(sig,((math.floor(padVal/2.0),math.ceil(padVal/2.0)),(0,0)),mode='edge')
    elif dimensions==1:
        return np.pad(sig,(math.floor(padVal/2.0),math.ceil(padVal/2.0)),mode='edge')
    else:
        print(f"Failure")
```

Then finally, correlate. I used both of them just to see if there was any difference. But they both return inf.

```
xcorr = np.correlate(a_padded,b_padded,mode="valid")
xcorr2 = signal.correlate(a_padded,b_padded,mode="valid",method="direct")
```

Interestingly, I also tried fast dynamic time warping and this gives me an error that it wants 1-D arrays. But as far as I can work out, `a_padded` and `b_padded` are 1-D. In the variable viewer they list as `ndarray` with size (57494,).

```
d, path = fastdtw(a_padded, b_padded, dist=distance.euclidean)
```

What is going on? As far as I can work out there are no nan or inf values in the two signals (i checked with np.isnan, np.isinf and the where function and it returns an empty array, so I assume there aren't any).

What I was expecting to happen is get a cross correlation so I can go on to determine by how much I need to shift signal b to be perfectly aligned with signal a. I know I've got a bit more code to do after performing `np.correlate`. But it got stuck there first.

Here is the variable browser:
[image]

These are what the two signals look like. they're pretty close here, but when you zoom in they are a couple hundred sample points shifted apart.
[image]